# CSS animation with jQuery on enter and leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a jQuery which is adding animation class on mouse enter and add another class when mouse leaves element, basically i want In and Out animation. I'm achieving fading In animation but when i leave with mouse, the element disappears without animation. So only showing is animated but not the leaving.

jQuery:

```
$('.menu > ul > li').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                if (getWindowWidth() >= responsiveBreakpoint) {
                    $(this).children('ul').removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass('fadeInDown');
                }
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                if (getWindowWidth() >= responsiveBreakpoint) {
                    $(this).children('ul').removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('fadeOutUp');
                }
            }
        });
```

CSS

```
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  }

  to {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInDown {
  animation: .2s ease;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
}

@keyframes fadeOutUp {
  from {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }

  to {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  }
}

.fadeOutUp {
  animation: .2s ease;
  animation-name: fadeOutUp;
}
```

And element which im trying to animate is styled like this:

```
> ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: $hover-and-dropdown-bg;
}
```

Comment: `display` can't be animated. Or shown, or hidden. Not intermediate level. Use kinds of opacities or something similar to achieve the same. However, I think you don't need the javascript code, you can achieve the same pure CSS (`:hover` pseudoclass) since your animations occurs in childrens.

Comment: i managed to animate display on mouse enter look at my code how, i just need the other way, on mouse leave

Comment: **NO**. You are animating `opacity`, but not `display`, because animate `display` is impossible by spec and by logic

Comment: You are right i am not animating display because its not possible, but you can do the trick to manually put display block on hover, then animate other properites with animation after. I made exactly that in my code, if it works on enter, there should be a trick for leaving

Comment: When you leaving, the first to apply is `display: none`, so there are no element visible to animate nothing more. As simple as this.

Comment: OK that now makes sense, why is display first to apply?

Comment: Not "the first", but since it is not allowed to animate, when you apply mouseleave all properties will be rendered same time, but the animated properties lost some time to completely animated, but display none will be applied inmediately without timeout. That's the reason. However, I think you can achieve the same only with opacity, or even with `max-height: 0` to `max-height: auto`. And if you have time, try to make it pure CSS. Less code, and cleanest

Comment: Look at my answer, below please, i tricked it

Comment: I don't like this code for a simple animation, I tell you that this javascript code is unneccessary. But if it fits into your requirements, go straight with it. Good luck!

Comment: Im allways open for new options, what would you change

Comment: I like more pure css animations, but you can't write a delay like your solution with js. The problem still is `display` animation, that's impossible to animate as I tell you. So don't worry, use your own solution, and in the future you can test animations pure css

Comment: About animating with display, not possible, but you can trick it buy delaying  it. Here is working demo: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/QEGmRL .

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i managed to do it, i tricked css to have animation with display property.

jquery

```
$('.menu > ul > li').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                if (getWindowWidth() >= responsiveBreakpoint) {
                    $(this).children('ul').css('display', 'block').removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass('fadeInDown');
                }
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                if (getWindowWidth() >= responsiveBreakpoint) {
                    $(this).children('ul').removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('fadeOutUp').delay(200).queue(function (next) {
                        $(this).css('display', 'none');
                        next();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```